# How to Covert ActivityGroup to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have developed a tab based applicaiton using the TabActivity, each tab item has a activity group,for Example:

```
Tab 1-> Acitivty Grouop (inside this: List Activity->Detail ACtivity)
Tab 2-> Acitivty Grouop (inside this: List Activity->List Activity->Detail ACtivity)
Tab 3-> Acitivty Grouop (inside this:List Activity->Detail ACtivity with two tabs)
Tab 4-> Acitivty Grouop (inside this: List Activity->List Activity->Detail ACtivity)
```

Since TabActivity is deprecated class i need to achive the same using the fragment.

I have manage to build the Tab using the fragment by followiing the below link,
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

can some one help me to build above tab items using the fragment.

Comment: so what problems you are facing while implementing tab using Fragments.

Comment: I'm having the problem to replace the activity group in the tab item 2,can you tell me how i can implement the below flow [Tab 2-> Acitivty Grouop (inside this: List Activity->List Activity->Detail ACtivity)]

Comment: You mean when you click on any tab the previous tab fragments are still there and you need to remove them?

Comment: Not really, I have created Two List Fragment to support for Tab item2,in my previous implementation i send the intent data, so with fragment how to i send data between fragment."http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html" i have checked the linked but my question is how to retrieve the data.

Comment: Make your List Object implements Parceable then send that data to another Fragment using final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("data", list.get(index));
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);

and while retrieving in next Fragment use - 
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
MyListObj obj = bundle.getParcelable("data");

Comment: this worked for me, one issue now i want to change the background of the container when different fragment load, how i do that.

Comment: You can change that when you click tab button to load new fragment or you do addToBackStack in same stack.

Comment: @sam can you share more info or code related this question?